# I have to figure out when someone comes to the first stop after bungee jumping. How would I do it?

Tags: energy, potential-energy, elasticity

This is the information I'm given.
John is attached to an elastic rope which is unstretched before John steps off the beam, and another end is fixed to a high beam. John then steps off the beam from rest towards an air rescue cushion located below. John did not hit the cushion. Given that:
Express the distance sm dropped by John before John comes instantaneously resting for the FIRST time in terms of m,  L₀ and k.

The Mass of John is m in kilograms,
The length of the rope is L₀ in meters,
The rope has a force constant to produce a meter of extension of k Nm-²
gravity is 9.81 ms-².

What I have so far is;
He would stop when gravitational potential energy = elastic energy.
It could be expressed by; Gravitational potential energy lost = Elastic Energy Gained.
Therefore; GPE = mgh and Elastic E = ½kΔx²

Then;

mgh = ½kΔx²

m(9.81)s = ½k(s - L₀)²

After this part I was stumped. Please guide me! Thank you!

Comment: You have a quadratic equation in $s_y$. All of the other parameters in the equation are constant. Do you know how to find the roots of a quadratic equation ?

Comment: No I don't actually. How would I do that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula